# controller type 'effort_controllers/JointPositionController' does not exist

Tags: ros, joint, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I am trying to get control over a revolving joint (it is for a pan-tilt camera unit). So far I followed the [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Control_with_Gazebo) but the suggested controller (effort_controllers/JointPositionController) apparently does not exist. The ROS-error is -->

---

Could not load controller 'MY_CONTROLLER_NAME' because controller type 'effort_controllers/JointPositionController' does not exist.

---

When I use the solution suggested by ROS -->

---

"Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types"

---

I get -->

---

types: ['controller_manager_tests/EffortTestController', 'controller_manager_tests/MyDummyController', 'effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController', 'joint_state_controller/JointStateController', 'position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController']
base_classes: ['controller_interface::ControllerBase', 'controller_interface::ControllerBase', 'controller_interface::ControllerBase', 'controller_interface::ControllerBase', 'controller_interface::ControllerBase']

---

It might be possible that I could use some other controller to achieve control over the revolving joint. Maybe the ''joint_state_controller/JointStateController'? However, I am still wondering why the tutorial suggests a controller which is not available.

I am using ROS-hydro and my Gazebo version is 1.9.3.

Any suggestions are very appreciated.
Marcus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/144556/controller-type-%27effort_controllers/jointpositioncontroller%27-does-not-exist/) by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2014-03-26

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How did you install ros_controllers, binaries or source?. What does `rospack find effort_controllers` yield?. It would seem that this package is either not present or its location is not in your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.

The `joint_state_controller/JointStateController` is a read-only controller that publishes the `/joint_states` topic, so not an option. You could however use the `effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController`. It all depends on how you wish to send control commands.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on 2014-03-27**:
Thx for the help!!!!
"rospack find effort_controllers" told me the package cannot be found. I simply: "sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-effort_controllers" and now it works. I have a Pan-Unit for my camera :)

**Comment by [botbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/27567/botbuilder/) on 2016-07-22**:
At what location did you save the effort_controllers folder?

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2017-07-26**:
does this means i cant' use joint_state_controller/JointStateController for a joint?

**Comment by [Cabbage](https://answers.ros.org/users/32159/cabbage/) on 2017-10-06**:
When I typed "sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-effort_controllers", I got the error of "E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-effort_controllers". Where can I find that package?

**Comment by [lotfishtaine](https://answers.ros.org/users/27094/lotfishtaine/) on 2019-10-04**:
Thanks for sharing this useful information with us here. It works for me on ros-melodic. I just install : "ros-melodic-effort-controllers" with :  sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-effort-controllers

**Comment by [ignacio](https://answers.ros.org/users/45287/ignacio/) on 2020-12-10**:
remember to run `sudo apt update`, just in case

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Run this command

sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-ros-control ros-melodic-ros-controllers

---

Originally posted by [ymzkp](https://answers.ros.org/users/72276/ymzkp/) with karma: 11 on 2021-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1